# Setting up third party status bar on dwm

Tags: configuration, window-manager, patch, dwm

I am trying to set up an external status bar in `dwm` windows manager (in particular I am trying with `polybar`), but there are some issues with windows placement:

- ***the bar needs its own space:*** if naïvely run on dwm `polybar` will generate its own window (completely undesirable), but even if you are little bit more clever and you pass `override-redirect = true` it will be put on top of existing windows, hiding their content; as suggested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/issues/1132#issuecomment-377501973) you need to reserve some space from `dwm` to put the bar there: how?
- ***I would like to hide:*** the default `dwm` bar is able to be hidden, releasing the screen space for windows, but I am wondering how to do the same if I force `dwm` to reserve some space for the other bar

The main problem is that I am not enough into `dwm`, so I am not as familiar as needed with its source code to cook up a custom solution on my own, is there any one able to give me some advice? or point out a useful patch?

P.S.: in general I didn't find any tutorial around on setting up another status bar for `dwm` (e.g. [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Polybar/comments/eh8xhd/is_there_a_tutorial_on_setting_up_polybar_with_dwm/) asked for the same resource but no one made a useful answer), so if any one is able to provide something like that

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get around diving into the dwm source code.

One thing that worked for me in the past was modifying how dwm handles its own bar to handle polybar. This means removing the code that renders the dwm bar but not the code that adds space at the top or bottom for the bar.

I don't use dwm and have only done this as a proof of concept and unfortunately don't have the patch anymore, but I can give a few pointers:

*Note: This is in reference to code at commit [`f09418b`](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/commit/f09418bbb6651ab4c299cfefbe1d18de401f630e.html). For other commits things may be different.*

- Set the `topbar` variable in `config.def.h` to the inverse of the `bottom` variable in the polybar config.
- Set the `bh` variable in `dwm.c` to the height of the bar in pixels (remove the existing assignment)
- Stop dwm from showing its own bar. This is the most difficult part because you can't just set `showbar = 0` and handling for the bar windows is scattered accross the entire code. Have a look at all the places the `barwin` variable of the `Monitor` struct is used.

For the second part about hiding the bar, the changes I suggested above will likely allow for you to toggle bar just the same. This will only toggle the space that dwm reserves for the bar, but not the bar itself. For that you will also need to call `polybar-msg cmd toggle`.

Comment: I'm currently trying something like this, but I decided to add a new independent bar instance (another member of Monitor) with a detectable name to make it easier to manage it and replicate/enhance if needed. I'm wondering if I will be able to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you still trying, which is very unlikely, I just added polybar with dwm, working the way I want.

I am posting screenshot. This is my setup
[image: dwm-with-polybar]

I can help you(or anyone) getting this if you want to.

- Summery is :

1. follow [polybar-dwm-module](https://github.com/mihirlad55/polybar-dwm-module) and install, make sure to read README and follow it along.
2. pull dwm source code, and add desired patches like vanitygaps etc., and ANYBAR patch and other as [polybar-dwm-module's](https://github.com/mihirlad55/polybar-dwm-module) README says
3. It should work but if doesn't post error here, I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider editing your answer to add (at least) a summary of the necessary steps to achieve the desired result.